# OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow

where I exchange SAML assertion for an access token however I am getting error

"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS50107: The requested federation realm object 'https://sts.windows.net/tenantid/' does not exist." ..

Can you please help me with what needs to be checked and what could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow is intended for federated domains only, more info [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45071#issuecomment-570539518), that thread has a more in depth discussion of the scenario.

Comment: this is a bit different, we have ADFS and federation with Azure ad ...so authentication is on-premise... so request go to Azure AD then it redirect to ADFS for password validation with AD.

Comment: @Suuny , Please check this doc [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40210)

Comment: I have opened a case with MS, lets c what could be the issue